# How to make Second Field Null if First Field has a Value in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns

I have two calculated Columns in ORACLE (Ex3 and EX12). So wherever BOTH fields have a value (ex: ID 118189AC) id like to keep the value in EX3 but turn the EX12 into a NULL. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT *

FROM 
(SELECT ID,

CASE
    WHEN PORT IN ('CAP')
    THEN 3
    ELSE NULL
END AS EX3,

CASE
    WHEN PORT NOT IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3')
    THEN 12
    ELSE NULL
END AS EX12

FROM LAN.DETAILS)
WHERE (EX3 IS NOT NULL OR EX12 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY ID ASC


ID         EX3     EX12
118051PU            12
118052PU            12
118189AC    3       12
118397PU            12
118451AC    3       12
119343AC    3       12
119387PU            12
119484PU            12
119772PU            12
119997PU            12
120320AC    3       12
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want a `case` expression:

```
select id, ex3,
       (case when ex3 is not null and ex12 is not null then null else ex12 end) as ex12
. . .
```

Comment: isnt EX12 already Aliased as a Caculated column in the From Subquery? Also Oracle doesnt let you reference other aliased column since everything runs in parallel. Not sure if im right but i've faced these issues before. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Manny . . . I don't understand your comment.  The two aliases are defined in the *subquery*, so of course they can be referenced and perhaps redefined in the outer query.

Answer (score 2):

`NVL2(a, b, c)` returns `b` if `a` is not null, `c` otherwise.

In your case:  `NVL2(ex3, null, ex12)` will return `null` when `ex3` is not null. Otherwise it will return `ex12`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions096.htm

Comment: So would this go in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Tried it and it works! Had to put it in the SELECT clause. I have multiple columns that would need to be compared like that but atleast it works. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a subquery in the WHERE clause that resricted the ID's that were being returned for EX3. Thanks Everyone